# Questions about custom Deflate implementation in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am currently working on a custom deflate algorithm that should be encapsulated in a custom class derriving from *System.IO.Stream*.

I know there **is** a .Net implementation of a *DeflateStream*, but I as well want to as well completely understand the algorithm as need to implement it because Silverlight what I am using doesn't include that class.

I already read some information about deflate und understand that deflate is a combination of *LZ77* and *Huffman-Encoding* and already spent some time for the *LZ77* implementation but now do have a few questions about it:

1) The output of LZ77 is a list of triplets (offset, length, successor). It isn't quite efficient to map them as three bytes, isn't it? What would you suggest? I an writing all output to an underlying *MemoryStream* which is only able to handle (a set of) bytes.

2) What size would you suggest to use for the sliding window?

3) I do know what Huffman coding is, but how do I apply it here? My problem is that I don't know what size of "chunks" I need to map with it and didn't find any information about this. Do I apply it for each byte? Two bytes? Three? And how do I handle the resulting output (same problem as mentionend in 1))? I thought about using a kind of state machine that continues reading bytes and extracting the *Huffman codes*, but this doesn't seem to be very efficient. Is there a better way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you implemented deflate algorithm on C#? Could you share this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't tell you for the first 2 points, but Huffman coding is basically about generating binary codes for each symbol in your sequence. Code length depends on how frequent the symbol is. The shorter codes are for populars and the longer ones are for unpopulars. The idea is like:

abaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

1. Use 1 for 'a'
2. Use 01 for 'b'

Comment: Yes, that's right. My problem isn't that I don't know how it works in general but how to apply this here. As I work on binary data only - do I have to set a fix size for one "symbol" (just like one byte or two), or is there a way of defining them programatically? And how do I count them? Do I really need to count each byte? How does this work for large files? There must be an efficient way to do this...